# hasClass does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a navigation system where left and right arrows expand LIs.

```
<a href="#" class="icon-arrow-left active"></a>
     <ul>
        <li class="contracted"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="expanded"><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="activeLesson"><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="expanded"><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li class="contracted"><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
<a href="#" class="icon icon-arrow-right active"></a>
```

When fist li is 'expanded' 'icon-arrow-left' should be 'inactive' and when last li is 'expanded' 'icon icon-arrow-right' should be inactive.

I tried to use this but not working

```
 if ($('li:first-child').hasClass('activeLesson')) {
        $('.icon-arrow-left').attr('class','inactive')
        }
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhP74/)

Comment: li:fist-child only gets the first li

Comment: Your if statement only happens once.... of course it isn't going to work. You need to place that inside of an event or function that gets called on an event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xhP74/2/

```
$('.arrowButton').find('.icon-arrow-left').click(function () {
    $('.lessonNavigation .expanded.right').attr('class', 'contracted');
    $('.lessonNavigation .activeLesson ').attr('class', 'expanded right');
    $('.lessonNavigation .expanded.left').attr('class', 'activeLesson');
    $('.lessonNavigation .activeLesson').prev().attr('class', 'expanded left');

    if ($('li:first-child').hasClass('activeLesson')) {
        $('.icon-arrow-left').toggleClass('active inactive');
    }
});
```

You have to place the if-statement inside an event, otherwise it only gets called on document ready.

Answer (score 2):

Move your code inside the click handle:

```
// Count Navigation quantity ==================================            
var count = $('.lessonNavigation li').length;

if (count > 4 && count <= 10) {
    $('.lessonNavigation li').attr('class', 'contracted');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:eq(0)').attr('class', 'expanded left');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:eq(1)').attr('class', 'activeLesson');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:eq(2)').attr('class', 'expanded right');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:eq(3)').attr('class', 'expanded');
}

// ========== Right and Left arrow functions ==================             
$('.arrowButton').find('.icon-arrow-right').click(function () {
    $('.lessonNavigation .expanded.left').attr('class', 'contracted');
    $('.lessonNavigation .activeLesson ').attr('class', 'expanded left');
    $('.lessonNavigation .expanded.right').attr('class', 'activeLesson');
    $('.lessonNavigation .activeLesson + li ').attr('class', 'expanded right');
});

$('.arrowButton').find('.icon-arrow-left').click(function () {
    $('.lessonNavigation .expanded.right').attr('class', 'contracted');
    $('.lessonNavigation .activeLesson ').attr('class', 'expanded right');
    $('.lessonNavigation .expanded.left').attr('class', 'activeLesson');
    $('.lessonNavigation .activeLesson').prev().attr('class', 'expanded left');

    if ($('li:first-child').hasClass('activeLesson')) {
        $('.icon-arrow-left').toggleClass('active inactive');
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xhP74/3/